# How to change AndroidManifest.xml file name?

Tags: java, android, ant, continuous-integration

I'm creating a build script for my CI and I want to change some fields in AndroidManifest.xml programmatically. So, I am running something like

```
transform_my_manifest AndroidManifest.xml NewAndroidManifest.xml
```

Now I want to build my android app with NewAndroidManifest.xml as manifest file.

Is there anything like

```
ant -DManifestFile=NewAndroidManifest release
```

Or maybe I should put something in `local.properties`?

P.S. I don't want to create `AndroidManifest.xml.template` in SCM and generate Mainfest file itself programmatically -- other developers use eclipse and quite happy, I don't want to bother them.

P.P.S. I *can* delete&rename for build process and rename&delete this file pair back at the end, but this is too "flammable" solution, I want better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything like: ant -DManifestFile=NewAndroidManifest release

No, sorry, not with Ant. The [new Gradle-based build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) will allow you to create a manifest from component parts and configure parts of it dynamically via the DSL, which may help you achieve your objectives without `transform_my_manifest`.

> Or maybe I should put something in local.properties?

There is nothing in `local.properties` that affects the name of the manifest file used at compile time.

Comment: A pity :(

Thank You, I will try gradle.

Comment: @Arenim: Note that the new Gradle-based build system is still a work in progress. As the saying goes, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

why not this:
1. `transform_my_manifest AndroidManifest.xml NewAndroidManifest.xml`
2. `rename AndroidManifest.xml oldAndroidManifest.xml`
3. `rename NewAndroidManifest.xml AndroidManifest.xml`
4. `build`

?

Comment: because next `scm update` will face conflict with transformed and non-transformed manifest. I can rename it back after build -- but I will have troubles when build fails. I can write one more hook for build failure but... well, as I written, it's too flammable :)

Comment: @Arenim one option is to not check AndroidManifest.xml into source control, but check in a template.  Then the build script creates the AndroidManifest.xml instead of a NewAndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Yes, thank You :)

As I've written, I don't want eclipse-powered developers to generate something with ant, which they don't have.

But it seems I'm going to do so, because of no other choices.